# Do cyberlimbs enhancements and customizations improve my physical limit?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

In Shadowrun 5, do cyberlimbs enhancements and customizations improve my physical limit?

Comment: @ Archaos: the book says: if there are more different studs for a task: the lowest stud is used for the calculation

Comment: I would change this answer to Yes because the rules are clear and no official FAQ exists (unless someone can point me to it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a FAQ, Pavao write :

> Do my cyberlimbs alter my Physical limit? 
>   No.

Comment: Interesting...I think I'll house rule it

Comment: Could we get a link to this FAQ? Or at least a pointer to where we could get this?

Comment: I work for the Shadowrun French translation. This FAQ is one  document in progress. I think it's somewhere in a Shadowrun's forum.

Comment: To clarify, [this has been answered by a freelancer writter](https://forums.shadowruntabletop.com/index.php?topic=11514.msg227674#msg227674) (Aaron/Pavao), and has not been incorporated into the official errata as far as I know. The community has widely accepted his wording as *RAI* and moved on.

Comment: @ShadowKras: Your link is giving me a database error: "Database Error: Please try again. If you come back to this error screen, report the error to an administrator."

Answer (score 10):

**Yes, they do**... *if* I understand the rules correctly. *If.* :)

> (...) other in-game mechanics such as Initiative and Inherent Limits
>   are modified by these augmentations [*namely, cbyerware or bioware*], which
>   means these bonuses need to be factored in during Step Eight: Final
>   Numbers.

SR5, p. 94-95, Cyberware and Bioware

Comment: Exactly. Whenever you increase your stats you should recalculate your limits.

Comment: If a character have a cyberarm with Strength 10 and other with Strength 8, how the limit is calculated ?

Answer (score 5):

### No

(based on the german books)

Improved attributes via cyberware are included in calculating limits.

Cyberlimbs do not modify your attributes. Therefore they are not included in the calculation.

German core rulebook on Cyberlimbs (p.461) explicitly states:

> Cybergliedmaßen haben ihre eigene Stärke und Geschicklichkeit.
>   Das heißt, sie unterliegen nicht der normalen Begrenzung von +4 auf den aktuellen Attributswert des Charakters, verändern aber auch nicht sein Körperliches Limit.

Translated roughly:

> Cyberlimbs do have their own Strength and Dexterity.
>   This means, they are not subject to the normal limit of +4 to the current character attributes, but do not change the physical limit.

**But:**
The german version of Chrome Flesh contains an optional rule:
If you have replaced all of your limbs with cyberlimbs, you may calculate the average Strength and Dexterity of all limbs and use this average to calculate your physical limit.

Comment: Do you know, and would clarify if you do, as to why the german *translation* of the game has so many changes and clarifications that can't be found even on the *english* errata of the game? This would help us decide if we should take it as an official source or not.

Comment: From reading much of the Pegasus forum: While translating the books, Pegasus asks for clarification and suggests errata to CGL (at least for the first few books they did intensely). If they got a response, they would adhere to CGL. Else they decide for themselves, which rules interpretation deems them right and clarify the rules to reflect this. So if there would be something for errata, CGL would have known it, but CGLs errata is a mess...